# What does the concept of "worker" mean in programming?

Tags: java, operating-system

I want to know What does the concept of "worker" mean in programming?
I've recently started Java and have seen in so many places where they are used but don't get the idea.

Examples would be great.

Comment: It is any component which does "real" work. c.f. messaging, control, gui compoenents.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A worker is something you give a task and continue in your process, while the worker (or multiple workers) process the task on a different thread. When they finish they let you know about it via a call back method. I.e. a special method provided on the initial call gets called.

Answer (score 0):

A worker generally refers to an application that performs tasks or processes data in the background without requiring direct user interaction. Workers are essential for handling time consuming or resource intensive operations **asynchronously**.

Written by @vordrax [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskProgramming/comments/c7hvt9/what_the_hell_are_workers/)

> When our organization uses the term "worker", it's just a generic term
> for application instance with a specific purpose. So we might have an
> application that handles a specific task, say consuming order messages
> and writing them to the database. That would be a worker. And if this
> work can be parallelized, we might have three copies of it running at
> the same time on the same server. So we'd have three workers running,
> handling this task.

Analogy written by @cyrusol [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskProgramming/comments/c7hvt9/what_the_hell_are_workers/)

> That model is comparable to cashiers in a supermarket. A job (client)
> can arrive in the queue (literally, the queue) and it is handled by a
> worker (cashier). With the slight difference that in most IT systems
> jobs don't "choose" the worker they are handled by but humans irl do
> by choosing a line to wait in.
>
> Workers normally have to do some payload that involves transforming
> data, redirecting it to another queue or external service etc. and it
> all happens asynchronously which means independent from the program
> executation that triggered the job.